# appropriate hypothesis test for non-negative quantity

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, population

This question is intentionally written in a very abstract way, because I am interested in a generic solution, or for pointers to different possible concrete cases in different fields:

I am measuring a particular quantity in a sample of subjects taken from a given population, and I want to apply a null hypothesis test to check whether there is evidence for "an effect" in that population. Under most circumstances, I would apply a one-sample t-test to test whether the population *mean* is different from zero.

In this case, however, I know that the underlying quantity can only be zero or positive, but *never negative*. In my view this invalidates the null hypothesis of a population mean of zero, because as soon as there is any variation across subjects in the population that mean has to be non-zero anyway. Or to put it differently: A t-test applied in such a situation effectively tests whether the *variance* in the population is non-zero, which however we usually assume to be the case anyway, because no person is exactly like the other.

The situation is complicated by the fact that I can only obtain estimates of that underlying non-negative quantity, where the sampling distribution can be safely assumed to be normal, so that in contrast to the true value these estimates can and will often be below zero.

Two questions:

- *Is this a known situation with a generic approach?* I couldn't find anything in standard textbooks on hypothesis testing.
- *Are you aware of instances of this situation?* It might help me get to the core of the problem if I can compare my concrete case to other concrete cases in different disciplines.

Comment: I like the question: can you say more about the *kind* of data other than that they are non-negative? For example, are you explicitly referring to *count* data? Not that you are, but if you were, you could perform hypothesis tests based on the Poisson distribution (or negative binomial distribution), rather than the *t* distribution. Also: I took the liberty of edit the last sentence in your first paragraph to avoid a misinterpretation of non-parametric tests.

Comment: @Alexis, if there's a misunderstanding on my part, please point it out to me, but: The nonparametric analogue I have in mind, the sign-permutation test, actually does test whether the *mean* is different from 0. Since this part is not essential, and might be misleading, I just deleted the parentheses. Ok?

Comment: You are mistaken. The sign test is a test for stochastic dominance, not a test for mean difference, its H$_0\text{: }\text{P}\left(X_{A} > X_{B}\right) = 0.5$ is explicitly a hypothesis about stochastic dominance, not about the mean.

Comment: @Alexis, I fear that if I give more details I'd receive answers that focus too much on technicalities, so I'd rather keep it like it is for the time being. But thank you for pointing out counts as a possible example. I'll read up on that case, but if you have the time it would be interesting to have a full answer from you on that case.

Comment: Well, if you are being vague about the nature of your data, I would not expect much beyond vague answers: (1) Yes, it is known. The "standard approach" is to apply a test based on an appropriate distribution. (2) Yes, I am aware of instances. I just gave you one. :)

Comment: Under (1), I'm interested in whether there's a generic approach, just as the t-test is (whether correctly or not) treated as the generic approach in a number of different empirical sciences. Your answer implies there is none. In that case, I'll wait for more examples. :)

Comment: @Alexis, I did a bit of research and now understand which sign test you refer to, and you are right in that case. However, what I meant was the *sign permutation test*, which is the permutation test analogue of the one-sample t-test, and therefore does test whether the mean is different. See Good, *Permutation, Parametric
and Bootstrap Tests of Hypotheses*, Sec. 3.2.1. To be precise though, this test is not nonparametric but semiparametric, since it uses the assumption of symmetry around the mean.